# terraform - mount EFS to ECS fargate: No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

I am trying to mount a persistent volume to a container but the container doesn't start because of the error: "No such file or directory".

Here the relevant configuration:

```
# EFS
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_nfs_inbound" {
  name   = "${local.resource_prefix}-allow-nfs-inbound"
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress {
    from_port        = 2049
    to_port          = 2049
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "all"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_efs_file_system" "persistent" {
  creation_token = "${local.resource_prefix}-efs"
  encrypted      = true
}

resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "mount_targets" {
  count = length(module.vpc.private_subnets)

  file_system_id  = aws_efs_file_system.persistent.id
  subnet_id       = module.vpc.private_subnets[count.index]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.allow_nfs_inbound.id]
}

resource "aws_efs_access_point" "assets_access_point" {
  file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.persistent.id

  root_directory {
    path = "/assets"

    creation_info {
      owner_gid   = 0
      owner_uid   = 0
      permissions = "755"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_efs_access_point" "shared_access_point" {
  file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.persistent.id

  root_directory {
    path = "/shared"

    creation_info {
      owner_gid   = 0
      owner_uid   = 0
      permissions = "755"
    }
  }
}

# ECS
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "backend_task_definition" {
  ...

  container_definitions = jsonencode(
    [

      {
        ...
        mountPoints = [
          {
            sourceVolume  = "assets"
            containerPath = "/app/assets"
            readOnly      = false
          },
          {
            sourceVolume  = "shared"
            containerPath = "/app/shared"
            readOnly      = false
          }
        ]
        volumesFrom = []
        ...
      }
    ]

  volume {
    name = "assets"

    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.persistent.id
      root_directory = "/assets"
    }
  }

  volume {
    name = "shared"

    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.persistent.id
      root_directory = "/shared"
    }
  }
  ...
}

resource "aws_security_group" "allow_efs" {
  name   = "${local.resource_prefix}-allow-efs"
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress {
    from_port        = 2049
    to_port          = 2049
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "backend_ecs_service" {

  ...

  network_configuration {
    subnets = setunion(
      module.vpc.public_subnets
    )
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.allow_efs.id]
    assign_public_ip = true
  }

  ...
}
```

The complete error message is:

> Resourceinitializationerror: failed to invoke EFS utils commands to set up EFS volumes: stderr: b'mount.nfs4: mounting :/assets failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory' : unsuccessful EFS utils command execution; code: 32

The network configuration should be correct because if I remove the security groups I get a different network related error.

**EDIT:**

Added docker `RUN`:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install git binutils && \
    git clone https://github.com/aws/efs-utils && \
    cd efs-utils && \
    ./build-deb.sh && \
    apt-get -y install ./build/amazon-efs-utils*deb

RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.5/get-pip.py -O /tmp/get-pip.py  && \
    python3 /tmp/get-pip.py && \
    pip3 install botocore
```

Comment: You cannot use EFS unless you have installed proper helper packages and tools in your Docker image. Which base image are you using?

Comment: That explains... It's a legacy project, I am using `node:14-buster` base image.

Comment: Ok, so if I am not mistaken, that's a Debian based image. You can see the instructions for installing everything you need here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/installing-amazon-efs-utils.html. Look at the `To build and install amazon-efs-utils as a Debian package for Ubuntu and Debian` section.

Comment: I added the `RUN` commands in the `Dockerfile` and it completes without errors but it seems like I still have the same error. Is there any other step to do?

Comment: Did you install the required Python packages as well?

Comment: You mean `botocore`? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/install-botocore.html

Comment: Yes, sorry, was typing in a rush.

Comment: Now I installed `botocore` too and I am getting the same error.

Comment: Can you add that `RUN` steps or those steps where you install everything to the question? Just so I can compare to what I have used.

Comment: Sure, I added the run steps to the question. In the second one I just installed the `pip` for the current `python3` in the container instead of using the `if/else` in the support page.

Comment: Ah, ok, are you running the container as a specific user or as root?

Comment: No, there aren't user related commands. It's all standard.

Comment: @MarkoE that's not true at all. You do not need EFS helper packages in the container image. The EFS volume is mounted by the Fargate host, and mapped to a docker volume in the container.

Comment: It's good I didn't post it as an answer then @MarkB. :) Always happy to hear how things can be done differently.

Comment: Beh thank you both for the support. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really not sure why you are getting that specific error. You might want to make sure you have `platform_version = "1.4.0"` in your `aws_ecs_service` resource definition. I think `1.4.0` is the default now, but you aren't showing your entire resource definition, and if you had it set to something like `1.3.0` that could cause this issue.

Also makes sure you have `launch_type = "FARGATE"` in the `aws_ecs_service` resource definition (again I'm having to guess, because you didn't include the full code). That error really sounds to me more like an issue that would happen with EC2 deployments running a custom EC2 AMI, than with Fargate deployments. So double check you are really deploying to Fargate.

Also, you aren't configuring ECS to use the EFS access point you have created. You should change your `volume` blocks to look like this;

```
  volume {
    name = "assets"

    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.persistent.id
      root_directory = "/assets"
      transit_encryption = "ENABLED"

      authorization_config {
        access_point_id = aws_efs_access_point.assets_access_point.id
        iam             = "ENABLED"
      }
    }
  }

  volume {
    name = "shared"

    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.persistent.id
      root_directory = "/shared"
      transit_encryption = "ENABLED"

      authorization_config {
        access_point_id = aws_efs_access_point.shared_access_point.id
        iam             = "ENABLED"
      }
    }
  }
```

---

Also, why are you doing `setunion()` here?

```
    subnets = setunion(
      module.vpc.public_subnets
    )
```

If your `module.vpc.public_subnets` are a list of sets, then you need to do `setunion()` everywhere you are accessing that module output variable, like in the `aws_efs_mount_target` resource. But if your `module.vpc.public_subnets` is not a list of sets then that function call is pointless.

Comment: It was the missing access point configuration in `efs_volume_configuration`! Now the deployment is working. BTW, the fargate version was already `1.4.0`. Regarding `setunion()`, I am pretty new in AWS and terraform, I copied and pasted that part. Probably isn't necessary https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest?tab=outputs `public_subnets` should be already a list.